# Sql Change Time in Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I currently have the following Problem, working on an Oracle Database:
I have 2 columns of an appointment I want to read: `date_from` and `date_to`. They have both DateTime as the datatype.

I need to adjust the time of the value though (and only the time, the date should stay the same).


`date_from` for example contains `10.10.2017 14:21:00` as a value,

but should be changed to the "start of the day" --> `10.10.2017 00:00:00`

 
`date_to` for example contains `11.10.2017 11:47:00` as a value,

but should be changed to the "end of the day" --> `10.10.2017 23:59:59`

 
Is this somehow possible to manipulate it this way? I ***can not*** do an Update or permanent change to the data. This Format is only needed for a Gantt Diagramm, I dont have an other way to change it.

 
Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Oracle does not have a `datetime` data type.

Comment: Use `trunc(date_from)` for first date and `trunc(date_to) + 1 - interval '1' second` for second, like [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7482/1).

Comment: @PonderStibbons I would suggest not mixing adding numbers and intervals in the second statement. Either `TRUNC( date_to ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND` or more simply `TRUNC( date_to ) + INTERVAL '23:59:59' HOUR TO SECOND`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this might be some help to you:

```
    SELECT to_char(current_timestamp,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss') FROM dual;

    SELECt trunc(current_timestamp)||'  23:59:59' FROM dual;
```

Comment: That is actually what I am searching for! The date is now exactly how I need it, I will try it out, hopefully it works with my Report!

Comment: You should not rely on implicit conversion of dates to string. If you do `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';` then your second query will be wrong and show two time components. Instead, explicitly use `TO_CHAR` with the format model you are expecting for your output.

Comment: @MT0 why to use hh24 then??

Comment: To show you that, without making any changes to your query, it will not give the desired results if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` changes because you are implicitly relying on the default format and this is not good practice.

Comment: i dont understand why an accepted answer is given a negative vote

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can achieve that with Oracle's TO_DATE and TO_CHAR functions. It will only depend if you need the result as a DATE or as a VARCHAR. The syntax would look like this for VARCHAR output:

```
TO_CHAR(date_from, 'DD.MM.YY') || ' 00:00:00'
TO_CHAR(date_to, 'DD.MM.YY') || ' 23:59:59'
```

If you need the DATE value from this, just add the TO_DATE funtion around it:

```
TO_DATE((TO_CHAR(date_from, 'DD.MM.YY') || ' 00:00:00'), 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')
TO_DATE((TO_CHAR(date_to, 'DD.MM.YY') || ' 23:59:59'),  'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS')
```

I did not test it, but it's pretty much it.

Does this helps?

Cheers

Nikao

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show the result, try this:

```
select to_char(date_from, 'DD.MM.YYYY') ||' 00:00:00' as date_from,
       to_char(date_to,   'DD.MM.YYYY') ||' 23:59:59' as date_to
  from table_name
```

But you may need to compare intervals. In this case, you could discarts the time using `trunc` function:

```
select *
  from table_dates t,
       other_table o
 where trunc(o.some_date) between trunc(t.date_from) and trunc(t.date_to)
```

**UPD**: First, I did an implicit conversion of dates to string using TRUNC. But it can lead to inexpected result. Instead, explicitly use TO_CHAR with the format model you are expecting for your output and you do not need to use TRUNC. (Thank you @MT0 )

Comment: You should not rely on implicit conversion of dates to string. If you do `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';` then your first query will be wrong and show two time components. Instead, explicitly use `TO_CHAR` with the format model you are expecting for your output and you do not need to use `TRUNC`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to return the start and end of the day?

```
select trunc(start_date) as day_start, -- Strips off the time part of the date
       trunc(end_date) + 1 - (1/86400) as day_end -- As above, but we add 1 day and minus 1 second
from My_Table
```

Also, Oracle has date formats of Date and Timestamp, no datetime